# CakePHP file download corrupted

Tags: cakephp, upload, download

I have a site where users can upload images and then download them. I have moved my project on a live web host but the problem is that when I try to download the file I just uploaded, it downloads it but cant open it afterwards, it says it is corrupted... I had no problems in local though.

heres my download action:

```
public function getfile($accesskey) {
       $this->autoRender = false;

        if ($accesskey != null) {
     $data = $this->getfileinfo($accesskey);
            if (!empty($data)) {

           $this->response->file(WWW_ROOT.$data['Document']['dlpath'], array('download' => true, $data['Document']['name']));

                return $this->response;
            } else {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'upload'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'documents', 'action' => 'upload'));
        }

    }
```

$data['Document']['dlpath']  contains the following:

> /home/vol2_2/byethost17.com/b17_15357734/htdocs/app/webroot/uploads/2014/09/26/filekey/imagename.extension

this is the first time i'm doing this so i might have made a mistake.. the path is wrong or something i'm confused

EDIT: It seems that the error i was getting was much deeper than it seemed. I opened the corruted file in a text editor and saw some error concerning set_time_limit() and php safe mode...

here's the error:

```
Warning (2) : set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons [ CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php , line 1458 ] Code Context 
set_time_limit - [internal], line ??
CakeResponse::_sendFile() - CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 1458
CakeResponse::send() - CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 429
MediaView::render() - CORE/Cake/View/MediaView.php, line 96
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 954
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 198
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 165
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 108
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the download function to blame and not the upload? Login at your server via ftp or something and have a look at the stored files, are they fine?

Comment: yes all the folders are created correctly and the file is moved in aswell, when I download the file from the FTP it's the correct one too.

Comment: How about describing exactly what your error inside that file is?